# comparing two PFFiles

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pffile

Is it possible to compare to `PFFiles`?
I am trying to check whether a downloaded `PFFile`:

```
let imageFile = object["groupImage"] as PFFile
```

is equal to a mock data created by me like this:

```
 let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "dot.png")!)
    uploadMock = PFFile(name: "mock", data: imageData!)
```

Now it happens when I call the comparison, it will not work.

```
if (mock?.isEqual(image))!{

            print(true)
        } else{

            print(false)

        }
```

will always give false, even though the images are the same.
It seems like it would be necessary, to download the image before. I tried to work around with checking the filename (it worked used to work until I transferred to another database).

Any ideas?

Comment: you mean you want to actually want to compare two images that each `PFFile` object points to?

Comment: exactly. the question is, is there a way without downloading it, since it would cost an api call

Comment: Not possible.  Consider the analogy on a local machine: it would be like comparing one file's name to another file's contents.